# Javascript Quantity Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm new to programming and still exploring. I just want to ask how to code this validation in JavaScript. I have a "Quantity" field in my form and "Quantity Remaining" showing how much quantity is left. What I want to do is to check in real-time, if the user entered a quantity greater than the "Quantity Remaining", an error message should occur, such as an `alert()`.

Here's my form if you want to check it out: [Screenshot](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/2157/capturetfp.png).

Comment: read some tutorials on javascript and give it a go. no matter how bad or wrong your code is, we're willing to help if you're willing to try. ;)

Comment: Tried some tutorials but doesn't work for me or my logic isn't that good enough :(

Comment: @Yassi show us the bare minimum of what you have tried, even if it doesn't work.  If we just give you the answer (which we probably could) you'll have to come back here every time you run into a block.  You need to learn to figure out the solution on your own

Comment: Guys I got it :) Thanks for all your help and suggestions I got the validation for javascript and also for Ajax. I've learned a lot from you. Here's my code which worked perfectly.  var qty = document.getElementById("item_quantity"+a).value;
      var rem_qty = document.getElementById("quantity_rem"+a).value;
      
      if(qty > rem_qty) {
         alert("Quantity Exceeds in line "+a+". \n");
         document.getElementById("item_quantity"+a).value='';
     }
       
          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Try this, it will helps you i think

```
<script>
 function check_qty() {
     var qty=document.getElementById('qty').value;
     var rem_qty=document.getElementById('rem_qty').value;
     if(qty>rem_qty) {
         alert("quantiy exceeds.");
         document.getElementById('qty').value='';
     } 
 }
</script>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="" onchange="check_qty();"/>
<input type="text" name="rem_qty" id="rem_qty" value="50"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x=document.getElementById("Qty").value;
var y=document.getElementById("QtyRemaining").value;
 if(y>x) {
  alert("exceeded the Qty remaining");
  document.getElementById("Qty").value = "";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" id="Qty" onBlur="myFunction()">
 <input type="text" id="QtyRemaining" value="2323">
</body>
</html>
```